# why is binder not finding a package?

Tags: python, binderhub

In my requirements.txt I have `geosampler==0.1.0` which then leads to the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement geosampler==0.1.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for geosampler==0.1.0
```

This package and version are available on PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/geosampler/

Why is binder failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made Python 3.9 or greater a requirement for your geosampler package (specifically shown [here](https://pypi.org/project/geosampler/0.1.0/) in left sidebar, towards the bottom '`Requires: Python >=3.9, <4.0`'). Launches currently from the [requirements binder repo example](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) are only Python 3.8.12. See [current version of runtime.txt](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements/blob/17ec0f6780408b532ce22854c321d4d807e59536/runtime.txt).

You can go [to this repo that is based on the requirements.txt example & has been configured to use Python 3.9](https://github.com/fomightez/testBinder39) (Python 3.9.12 at present) by editing `runtime.txt`, and click on the badge to launch a session served via MyBinder.org. (Or just [click here to launch](http://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/testBinder39/master).) You'll see there I added `geosampler==0.1.0` in the list in [requirements.txt](https://github.com/fomightez/testBinder39/blob/073b628908601ef0c03fe9444ad5e15b48925036/requirements.txt) and the image builds properly & when the session launches, running `import geosampler` in a cell works.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, it now works perfectly. Furthermore, your explanation was so good that I even helped me understand why colab was also not finding it (as it currently runs python3.7)! Many thanks for contributing to my learning.